# Cannot start DirectX 11 executable with Visual Studio, Build works properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, directx, directx-11

Following is Directx 11 code, that displays a window and keeps it open waiting for messages:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(_In_ HWND   hwnd, _In_ UINT   uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY) {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

// Directx main
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR cmd, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX window;
    ZeroMemory(&window, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    window.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    window.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW;
    window.hInstance = hInstance;
    window.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    window.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)"MainWindow";   // class name
    window.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&window);

    HWND windowHandle = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)"Main Window", (LPCWSTR)"DirectX Tut!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 600, 800, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

    if (!windowHandle) 
        return -1;

    ShowWindow(windowHandle, nCmdShow);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))    // continuously loop for messages
    {
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`stdafx.h` is a precompiled header file in which i include all the DirectX includes. Namely in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;`

I also include the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;` libraries located in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64`

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Windows 8.1 64bit. I followed [this](https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-setting-up-directx-12-for-visual-studio-2015) tutorial to create Directx application. Simply made a Win32 project, done these modifications in include and libs, pasted the code and built it properly. Running however does not output anything. It just says build succeeded. VS works with all my other projects. I have tried all configurations in x64 mode. If i had to guess i'd say that it is not finding a dll.. I cannot find the culprit.

Comment: Code looks fine, main window should show up but since you have not have not handled WM_PAINT, blank client area should be visible. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the window is not appearing, aka the application does not run. It builds perfectly fine though.

Comment: You should debug and find out why it's failing. It might be returning -1 because of invalid window handle?

Comment: Yes, this is what's happening! It didn't show me the output number when i wasn't debugging.

Comment: I spotted the error. It should be `(LPCWSTR)"MainWindow"` not `(LPCWSTR)"Main Window"` when creating the window handle. Thanks for the help. I am just starting DirectX programming and i was a bit confused, as to whether i forgot something else more critical.

Comment: Ya, I was about to post it. GetLastError was returning 1407 which is equivalent to "Cannot find window class"

Comment: Thanks. You can post an answer if you want and i will accept it.

Comment: Done, you might have noticed weird character showing up in the title. I have posted a fix for that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified "MainWindow" as it's class name when registering window class but when creating window you have specified ""Main Window", so Windows was unable to find that class. Passing "MainWindow" as it's class name to CreateWindow will fix that issue:

```
window.lpszClassName = L"MainWindow";   // class name
window.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

RegisterClassEx(&window);
HWND windowHandle = CreateWindow(L"MainWindow", L"DirectX Tut!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    100, 100, 600, 800, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);
```

As shown above, you should use L as a prefix for wide character string literals